# SQL IN subquery

Tags: mysql, sql

Im trying to do a query which looks like this:

```
SELECT `online`.user_id, users.profile_image_url, profile_info.profile_text, users.kind_of_relationship, users.gender_search, users.country
FROM `online`, users, profile_info 
WHERE (`online`.user_id = users.id)
AND (`online`.user_id = profile_info.profile_user_id)
AND (users.user_age >= '25' AND users.user_age <= '38')
AND (users.kind_of_relationship = 'Friendship')
AND (users.gender = 'female')
AND users.country IN (SELECT searching_countries.country FROM searching_countries, `online` WHERE `online`.user_id = searching_countries.user_id);
```

**and it fails.**

However if i run this query like this

```
SELECT `online`.user_id, users.profile_image_url, profile_info.profile_text, users.kind_of_relationship, users.gender_search, users.country
FROM `online`, users, profile_info 
WHERE (`online`.user_id = users.id)
AND (`online`.user_id = profile_info.profile_user_id)
AND (users.user_age >= '25' AND users.user_age <= '38')
AND (users.kind_of_relationship = 'Friendship')
AND (users.gender = 'female')
AND users.country IN ('Sweden', 'Austria');
```

**then the query works fine.**

Also if i only run the query:

```
SELECT searching_countries.country FROM searching_countries, `online` WHERE `online`.user_id = searching_countries.user_id
```

Im getting the result Sweden, Austria..

Any ideas why this **IN(SELECT searching_countries.country FROM searching_countries, `online` WHERE `online`.user_id = searching_countries.user_id) doesn't wanna to work?**

Thank you in advance!

Comment: what do you mean by `fail`? query does not return exact results? or it has syntax error?

Comment: Hi,
Well it's displaying NULL. Thats the problem

Answer (score 0):

```
UNION SELECT `online`.user_id, users.profile_image_url, profile_info.profile_text, users.kind_of_relationship, users.gender_search, users.country FROM `online`, users, profile_info  WHERE (`online`.user_id = users.id) AND (`online`.user_id = profile_info.profile_user_id) AND (users.user_age >= '25' AND users.user_age <= '38') AND (users.kind_of_relationship = 'Friendship') AND (users.gender = 'female') AND users.country IN ('Sweden', 'Austria');
```

Answer (score 0):

add an `ALIAS` for the `online` table in your subquery.

```
SELECT ...
FROM...
WHERE....
...AND (users.gender = 'female')
AND users.country IN
(
SELECT searching_countries.country 
FROM searching_countries, `online` x
WHERE x.user_id = searching_countries.user_id
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this done the trick and here is my solution now.

Sorry if there has been any missunderstanding but i still want to share how i solved my problem by doing an in. Things dont need to be that complecated sometimes :)

```
SELECT `online`.user_id, users.user_name, users.profile_image_url, profile_info.profile_text, users.kind_of_relationship, users.gender_search, users.country
FROM `online`, users, profile_info  
WHERE (`online`.user_id = users.id)
AND (`online`.user_id = profile_info.profile_user_id)
AND (users.user_age >= '25' AND users.user_age <= '38')
AND (users.kind_of_relationship = 'Friendship')
AND (users.gender = 'female')
AND users.country IN (SELECT country FROM searching_countries WHERE user_id ='55');
```